# como añadir un caracter al final de un resultado SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Necesito añadir el símbolo del dólar al final del resultado de una suma, cómo lo hago? con substring?

'''
SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) AS total_sales
FROM [Order]
'''

Comment: No deberías de hacer eso en la consulta. Tienes que dejar el formato en la capa de presentación.

Comment: Adhiero a lo que dice Luis, pero si lo necesitas de todas formas tienes que convertir la suma en un varchar y luego concatenarle el $.